# If I add and ignore a file in one branch, do I have to manually ignore the file in other branches?

Tags: git, branch, ignore

I have a repository with main, dev and feature branches. I created a few files in a feature branch and included them in `.gitignore`. I don't believe the files were ever added/committed to that branch. If I go back to one of the other branches they show up as new/addable files in that branch (not ignored). Do I have to manually update `.gitignore` in every branch or is there a way to make that "just happen". The files are unique to this repo so the global `.gitignore` isn't really the answer.

It's mainly a matter of being skittish when I see a credentials file or other files that I don't want committed show up as addable in other branches. I'm not quite ready to merge the feature back to the other branches either.

Comment: `.gitignore` is just a file like any other file: if you make changes to it in one branch, they're not going to be automatically reflected in other branches, unless they're forked from one that already has the change.

Comment: [Edited for clarity] Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Doesn't hurt to dream though. To expand though, let's say you add a password file and maybe some temp files to a feature branch and `.getignore` them, they show as addable in the development and main branches. If you add the files to `.getignore` in the dev and main branches, are those now ahead of the feature branch?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this particular problem.  (There are several one-size-fits-none answers, but don't use those, they don't fit. )  As [larsks mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301675/if-i-add-and-ignore-a-file-in-one-branch-do-i-have-to-manually-ignore-the-file#comment126033586_71301675), `.gitignore` is an ordinary file, stored like any other file in ordinary commits, so if you need it updated, you'd need to update it in each branch-tip.

What *may* work is to list the files—the ones you'd like Git to shut up about—in `.git/info/exclude`.  This file is not a working-tree file under version control (by definition: it's inside the `.git` repository directory itself), so it is not removed and replaced by `git switch` or `git checkout`.  A file name or pattern listed in `.gitignore`, or one listed in `.git/info/exclude`, or one listed in your global `.gitignore`, is treated the same way, regardless of which of these three files lists the name-or-pattern (with the exception of precedence, but the `info/excludes` file overrides the `.gitignore` file so you're good there).

This file is not copied by cloning, so it's not a general solution.

> To expand though, if you change `.gitignore` in the other branches without merging, does that make the branch ahead of the feature branch?

I'm not sure which branch you mean by *the* branch (first you have the plural, "other branches", then the singular, "the branch"), but if you add a new commit to some branch, that branch has advanced by one commit and is now "ahead".  So I *think* the answer you're looking for here is "yes".

Comment: I edited the comment to make it more clear, but I think you thought correctly. One thing I probably need to remember is that the files show as addable in the branches that don't have the `.gitignore` file yet, not added.